# How to bind md-progress-spinner's color in Angular 2 Material 2, to a custom color?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I want to use md-progress-spinner, to display percentage of the work done, yet I want to change it's stroke color from red to green dynamically based on the percentage.

How can I do that?

```
<md-progress-spinner 
     class="number" 
     mode="determinate" 
     [value]="today?.MemorizationPercent" 
     [style.background]="today?.MemorizationStateColor">
</md-progress-spinner>
```

Answer (score 12):

After reading the comments while looking for a solution to my own problem, I was able to come up with the following fix. It's not pretty, but until they open up the color attribute to accept more than three colors, this will serve as a temporary solution.

The spinner is an SVG circle, so it's properties can be modified via CSS. You can change the color of the circle with *stroke*, and the background of the circle with *fill*.

In the HTML:

```
<mat-spinner class="very-pink"></mat-spinner>
```

In the CSS:

```
.very-pink::ng-deep circle {
  stroke: fuchsia;
}
```

Here is a link to a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tswhgf) demonstrating it.

**EDIT:** Thanks to ConquerorsHaki for pointing this out - **[/deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep have been deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)**. For the moment they still work, and one would hope that a migration script will be provided before they kill it. That said, this is not an optimal solution.

Comment: Don't use ng-deep anymore as it will be (or is) deprecated, see:
https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: @ConquerorsHaki This is quite true. ::ng-deep is deprecated, as is the concept of a deep selector from W3. However, outside of ng-deep, I haven't found a simple way to accomplish this.

I will say, there was a comment last year that said that before it was removed, migration documentation would be provided. I kind of think they're banking on a suitable replacement becoming better supported in IE by then.

[link to comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17867#issuecomment-312322174)

Comment: Maybe Material theming is the way to go? I am not sure:
https://material.angular.io/guide/theming.

Comment: it's still a working solution. angular 6.0 and material 2

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `demo-app` example https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/demo-app/progress-spinner

You need to bind to `[color]` property.

Then in your code you can keep the logic that will change the color dynamically as you need based on your percentage value. e.g:

Template:

```
<md-progress-spinner 
     class="number" 
     mode="determinate" 
     [value]="today?.MemorizationPercent" 
     [color]="getColor(today?.MemorizationPercent)">
</md-progress-spinner>
```

Function `getColor()`sample:

```
getColor(percentage) {
   return percentage > 50 ? '_red_' : '_green_';
}
```

You need to define the colors in your custom material palette.

**UPDATE:**

**important** notice on your `'_red_'` and `'_green_'` colors:

> The color of the progress-spinner. Can be primary, accent, or warn

As per `progress-spinner` source code https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/progress-spinner/progress-spinner.ts#L110

```
/** The color of the progress-spinner. Can be primary, accent, or warn. */
  @Input()
  get color(): string { return this._color; }
  set color(value: string) {
    if (value) {
      this._renderer.removeClass(this._elementRef.nativeElement, `mat-${this._color}`);
      this._renderer.addClass(this._elementRef.nativeElement, `mat-${value}`);
      this._color = value;
    }
```

So `getColor()` becoming like say:

```
getColor(percentage) {
   return percentage > 50 ? 'accent' : 'warn';
}
```

If you not happy with any colors from prebuild theme palettes than you have to create our own, see https://material.angular.io/guides for more details

Comment: `color='red'`, `[color]='red'`, [color]='functionThatReturnsColor()'`, none of them work. It only accepts one of the three predefined `primary, accent, warn` colors.

Comment: Your GitHub page doesn't add anything. How do you make it red for example?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati that is sounds like another question ;) that is first, second I am just wondering why would you down vote the answer without a reason. The question is `How to bind md-progress-spinner's color in Angular 2 Material 2?` and the initial answer was as simple as `Use the [color] property`.

Comment: However the answer how to set your own colors you can find here https://material.angular.io/guides. Basically you need to create a custom pallete that contained all your colors otherwise you might consider to create a new question.

Comment: I didn't downvote. That's not me. I'm totally against downvoting. You can literally see that in my profile page.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati ahh just indecently was mentioned you, and by the way sounds like you cant see the who was downvoting https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317639/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-downvotes-removed